# Joining 2 images by using PHP GD & Image Functions

Tags: php, php-gd

I am creating a plugin where i am using a font file to generate the text, then converting it to image and attaching 2 chains on both side to give it a proper look.

[image: Nameplate Image]

But problem is the chains on both side are given by position, so that's obviously not going to touch the text for each and every alphabet.

Any different solutions to make it as intended. I am posting the current code, please let me know how to fix this and attch the chains to the starting and ending alphabet.

```
$text  = isset( $_POST['title'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['title'] ) ) : '';
$color  = isset( $_POST['color'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['color'] ) ) : '';
$st yle  = isset( $_POST['style'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['style'] ) ) : '';
$align  = isset( $_POST['align'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['align'] ) ) : '';

ob_start();

// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$file_id = get_field( "style", $style );
$font = get_attached_file( $file_id['id'] );

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 400);
$color_code = imagecolorallocate($im, 192, 192, 192);

// Create some colors
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
imagealphablending($im, false);
$transparency = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $transparency);
imagesavealpha($im, true);

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($chain_link_l);
$chain_l = imagecreatefrompng($chain_link_l);
$chain_r = imagecreatefrompng($chain_link_r);

$font_size = kp_create_fontsize(60, $font, $text, $align);

// Get Bounding Box Size
$text_box = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0,$font,$text);

// Get your Text Width and Height
$text_width = $text_box[2]-$text_box[0];
$text_height = $text_box[7]-$text_box[1];

// Calculate coordinates of the text
$x = 200 - ($text_width/2);
$y = 250 - ($text_height/2);
$chain_l_x = $x - 80 + 15 ;
$chain_r_x = $x + $text_width - 23 ;

imagecopyresampled($im, $chain_l, $chain_l_x, 50, 0, 0, 100, 200, $width, $height);
imagecopyresampled($im, $chain_r, $chain_r_x, 50, 0, 0, 100, 200, $width, $height);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, $font_size, 0, $x+2, $y, $grey, $font, $text);
imagettftext($im, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $color_code, $font, $text);

imagepng($im);
$imagedata['src'] = base64_encode ( ob_get_contents() );
ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I was trying to follow this funtionality, https://www.soufeel.com/necklaces/design-your-name-necklace, can you suggest if i can prepare this with other technology instead of php ?

Comment: The points where exactly those chains need to attach will differ between different letters - so unless you want to program an AI to figure this out, I guess your best bet is to figure out the necessary “adjustments” for different letters up-front, and then correct your position calculation accordingly, based on what the first and last letter of the user’s input were.