# How to get top point of text from image created in imagettftext()?

Tags: php, gd

[image]

I was creating an image from text by using `imagettftext()`, and need to attached a chain in to it on both left and right. By using `imagettfbbox()` i somehow manage to get point a and b, but i need the point `e and f` . Can some one please help me out here. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a way to get those particular points or a dynamic way to achieve points based on what it is written inside the box?

Comment: Yes, by dynamically is it possible .

Comment: And under how many StackOverflow accounts are we discussing our problem today, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54976796/

Answer (score 0):

Well this could be made in many ways. So you have a box and inside the box there's a name. This is what I would try first: You could divide the image in two horizontal sides:

[image: Dividing horizontally]

Then take the top half and get the most left pixel that match a color different from the background, which you can get using [`imagecolorat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php).

This will get you these points:

[image: Points shown]

Which I think is more realistic than attaching the chain to the `K` since it would be unbalanced.

I don't know if this would work on every single case but you can adjust the dividing phase to get you higher or lower points. Let me know what are your thoughts.

Must think of a good way to check pixel colors without checking every single one.